# jsonでグルーピングのようなことをしたい

Tags: java, json

今、json形式のpropertiesファイルを読むのを勉強しているものです。
そこで一つ詰まったところがありました。

```html
{
  "banana":{"type":"fruits", "color":"yellow"}
  "carrot":{"type":"vegetables", "color":"red"}
  "lemon":{"type":"fruits", "color":"yellow"}
  "apple":{"type":"fruits", "color":"red"}
}
```

このとき "banana" と "lemon" は中身が同じなので纏めて書きたいのですが、どのように書けばいいんでしょうか？

Comment: 纏めたいとはどのように纏めたいのでしょうか？求める結果を書いてください。

Comment: @user37032 さん、JSONはJSONでしかなく、それをどう書いたりどう読まれたりするかはアプリケーション依存なので、「propertiesファイル」というのが何なのかの説明があった方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: @itmammoth さん、その求める結果が分からないというご質問かな、と思いました。